# How to catch an exception from image onload

Tags: javascript, image, exception, try-catch

I cannot figure out how to catch an exception from a function that gets called from `image.onload`. Notice the following example:

```
function afterImgLoads() {
     throw 'This is being thrown from img.onload!';
}

try {
    var img    = new Image();
    img.onload = afterImgLoads;
    img.src    = 'path/to/valid/image.jpg';
} catch(e) {
    throw 'This is being thrown after setting img.src';
}
```

In the above example, I cannot figure out how to get the second throw statement to be thrown when `afterImgLoads()` throws its own error.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is impossible for that catch to throw statement since the onload happens asynchronously.

Answer (score 6):

You maybe able to use `onerror`

```
img.onerror = onErrorFunction;
```

It will call that function in the event of an error loading the image

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I'm not concerned about a failure to load the image. I am attempting to run other code AFTER the img loads successfully, and I want to throw a custom exception if THAT process goes bad.

Comment: then just run that code you want to have an exception for in your `afterImageLoads` function 
`function afterImageLoads(){ try{} catch(e){} }` 
Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: actually I am already doing that but my example is simplified. Ultimately, I need to throw, not catch, from afterImageLoads(), and catch THAT exception elsewhere. Fortunately, I found a different overall approach to what I was originally trying to accomplish, so I have given up on this approach for now.

Comment: Okay I understand now. Sorry I couldn't help then.

Answer (score 0):

You can set window.onerror which will be called on an otherwise uncaught exception anywhere on your page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try catching the error from the `onLoad` function

```
function afterImgLoads() {
  throw 'This is being thrown from img.onload!';
}

let img = new Image();
img.onload = () => {
  try {
    afterImgLoads();
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn(e);
  }
}
img.src = "https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/bear-monochrome-image-head-on-260nw-579987739.jpg";
```